# A class modeling a M:N relationship in Java: remember instances or just primary keys?

Tags: java, relationship

I have a class `Lease` modeling a relationship between classes `Customer` and `VideoGame`. Pretty simple and straightforward; it looks something like this:

```
class Lease() {
    private VideoGame videoGame;
    private Customer customer;
    // etc.
    public Lease(VideoGame videoGame, Customer customer) {
        this.videoGame = videoGame;
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}
```

Each of the three classes is represented by a database table with an autogenerated index and additionaly the `leases` table has a foreign key to reference both `Customer` and `VideoGame`.

While retrieving a `Lease` from the database, should I...

1. proceed to retrieve both `VideoGame` and `Lease` instances in my `getLease(long id)` method, and store those objects in the `Lease` instance
2. or, is it better for the `Lease` class only to remember the "foreign keys" and I should only actually retrieve a instance of `Customer` and `VideoGame` when needed? This would require the `Lease` class to change to

   class Lease() {
       long videoGame;
       long customer;
       // etc.
   }

The **first** approach seems more natural, however I'm looking for some "best practices" kind of advice on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ORM framework (Hibernate, JPA etc) you should create classes relationship as you want, i.e. typically using class-to-class relationship. The framwork is responsible on creating queries and saving primary keys in DB tables.

If you do not use any framework it is up to you where to convert keys to objects and how to create you model, however using objects in model is more natural.

Comment: Thanks, definitely feels more natural. I'll stick to objects in model.